# Access Method from a usercontrol in ASP.net

Tags: user-controls

I have a usercontrol in my ASP.net page. I have a method ProcessData() in my asp.net page.

How do I access ProcessData() method which is in the aspx page from my usercontrol?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

From your user control, cast this.Page as whatever type your page code behind class is. Then, you should be ale to call the method on that object.

Comment: Also, you want to make sure that your method is public.

Comment: smercer, do you have a sample by any chance??

Comment: Try the example at this link a little ways down the page it talks about the need to cast the Page property to the proper derived type...http://aspalliance.com/67

Comment: Spot on, ewrankin. The "Specific Parent Page" example is just what you need.